# Check if node contains any element with class

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I have a NodeList. I want to check every node, one by one, if it contains any element with specific class.

I am aware of Node.contains() method, but I can't figure out how to search for any element with certain class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is usually the easiest. Alternatively, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert NodeList to an array, and then use any array functions to filter what you want. In this case, I'm using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) grabbing only those that contain any element with `.test`:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div');

const filtered = [...nodes].filter(el => el.querySelector('.test') !== null);

console.log('All nodes:', [...nodes]);
console.log('Filtered:', filtered);

console.log('Filtered (outerHTML):', filtered.map(el => el.outerHTML));
```

```html
<div><span class="test" /></div>
<div><span class="rawr" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized from you answer that I could run querySelector('.test') on each node item. :)

Answer (score -2):

you can use this

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")).some(({classList}) =>classList.contains('requiredClass'))
```